# Collinear Divergences and SCET (Soft Collinear Effective Theory)

Tags: particle-physics, renormalization, scattering, singularities, scattering-cross-section

Can someone elaborate on how to treat collinear divergences in massless fermionic theories, such as the massless QED? Some very basic words on where do we can find such divergences and how to cure them (if we can cure them) would be nice...

Comment: Maybe the lecture notes by Tomasz Taylor that give a detailed account of collinear divergences in Yang-Mills theory are useful to you: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.05670

Comment: Moreover, the origin of these divergences is that if you have a vertex coupling two external particles of momenta $p_1$ and $p_2$ and one internal virtual particle of momenta $p_1+p_2$ the propagator of the virtual particle goes like $$\dfrac{1}{(p_1+p_2)^2}=\dfrac{1}{2p_1\cdot p_2}.$$ This diverges when the particles become cllinear, i.e., when $p_1\propto p_2$. Observe that in that limit the internal propagator goes on-shell because $(p_1+p_2)^2\to 0$.

Comment: These divergences are *very* important for Celestial Holography. If we write $p_i = \omega_i q(z_i,\bar z_i)$ where $q(z,\bar z)$ is the map from the celestial sphere to null directions $$q(z,\bar z)=(1+z\bar z,z+\bar z,-i(z-\bar z),1-z\bar z)$$ then $p_i\cdot p_j \propto |z_{12}|^2$. As such the limit in which $p_1$ and $p_2$ become collinear is a coincidence limit on the celestial sphere. In that sense, collinear divergences map to a celestial OPE. Some possibly relevant refs: https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.07424, https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.07763, https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.08799